# Problem removing annotation from mapView

Tags: iphone, crash, mapkit, mkannotation

I am storing all the annotations I am adding in a separate array. When I try to remove an annotation that has been added to the mapView using the following code:

```
if(![newClusters containsObject:cluster]){
    [__mapView removeAnnotations:[__clusterAnnotations objectAtIndex:[__clusters indexOfObject:cluster]]];
    [__clusterAnnotations removeObjectAtIndex:[__clusters indexOfObject:cluster]];
    [__clusters removeObject:cluster];
}
```

I get the following error:

```
-[ClusterAnnotationClass countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm not sure what this means, and I can add in any annotation just fine. It crashes when removing from the mapView.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `removeAnnotations` (plural) which takes an array of annotations but it looks like the object you are passing it is not an array.

Perhaps you meant to call `removeAnnotation` (singular)?

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks for catching it.